# Why is my DB context being disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

As with most of my recent posts, I will start by saying this is all new to me, and I am on the edge of my understanding. I am working on an existing application and have come across the above error.

The application is an MVC application that has 3 layers, and is being run through Swagger:

```
Rest

Services

DAL
```

In the service layer `DependencyConfig`, I do the following in the `Register` Method, the context is registered:

```
container.RegisterWebApiRequest<DbContext>(() => new LocalContext("name=DefaultConnection"));
```

So far this all seems to be working fine, as parts of the application are reading and writing from the database - although there is a lot in this application and I do not understand all of it.

Next, on the Rest layer, I have the following:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private readonly WindowsAuthenticationProvider _windowsAuthentication;
    private readonly AuthorizationManager _authorizationManager;
    private readonly IApplicationUserService _userService;
    private readonly IProfileService _profileService;
    private readonly IAccountLogsService _accountLogsService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="authorizationManager">Authorization Manager</param>
    /// <param name="windowsAuthentication">Enables windows reauthentication without a session</param>
    public AccountController(AuthorizationManager authorizationManager, WindowsAuthenticationProvider windowsAuthentication,
        IApplicationUserService userService, IProfileService profileService, IAccountLogsService accountLogsService)
    {
        _windowsAuthentication = windowsAuthentication;
        _authorizationManager = authorizationManager;
        _userService = userService;
        _profileService = profileService;
        _accountLogsService = accountLogsService;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get logged in user details
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Retrieves details of the currently logged in user</remarks>
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(AccountDetailsModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult Details()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();

        var model = //...

        if (model.HasAccount)
        {
            var user = _authorizationManager.FindUser(User.Identity);
        }

        return Ok(model);
    }
 }
```

and also from the services layer:

```
public class AuthorizationManager
    {
        private readonly IApplicationUserService _userService;

        public ApplicationUser FindUser(IIdentity identity)
        {
            var userId = identity.GetUserId<int>();
            if (userId != 0)
            {
                return _userService.FindById(userId);
            }

            //...
        }
    }
```

and finally also on the services layer:

```
public class ApplicationUserService : UnitOfWork<LocalContext>, IApplicationUserService
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole, int> _roleManager;

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds a user by id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">User id</param>
        /// <returns>ApplicationUser</returns>
        public ApplicationUser FindById(int id)
        {
            return _userManager.FindById(id);
        }
}
```

Where `ApplicationUser` is a model on the DAL layer.

I hope this all makes sense so far!

The problem is that when the code gets to this line:

```
return _userManager.FindById(id);
```

it throws an `InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.`

Which seems to me to be saying it has lost the context eg database connection.

It seems to have disposed of the DbContext from the register method - but I have no idea why?

If I manually create a context like this:

```
Context.Users.Find(id);
```

I am able to retrieve the required entry, but the problem re occurs further down the line - and I do not think the application was intended to work like this.

So my question is, why is it disposing of my context and how can I stop it doing so?

Stepping through the code does not help and I am out of ideas.

Comment: Please post `UserManager` code as well.

Comment: @Developer it is part of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

Comment: Anything interesting in `ApplicationUserService` constructor?

Comment: @Developer no nothing that could affect this. From looking further I think it is because applicationUser is declared with lifestlye.scoped and is being disposed of too early, but if I change its lifestyle I get simple injector exceptions

Comment: Do any of your services implement `IDisposable`, and if so, do they dispose of the context? If you're using dependency injection, the DI container should be responsible for the lifetime of the objects it injects. It will take care of disposing what needs to be disposed when.

Comment: @ChrisPratt only 1 class uses IDisposable, but it is in the DAL layer - could this still affect this from there?

Comment: The layer it's in is inconsequential. Does it dispose of your context in its `Dispose` method? If so, remove that, and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @ChrisPratt As far as I can see it is not disposing the context - it calls _transaction.Dispose() but that does not seem to be the context.

Comment: @ChrisPratt could this be the cause of the problem: container.Register<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, UserStore
                        <ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole,
                            ApplicationUserClaim>>(Lifestyle.Scoped); eg lifestyle.scoped ?

Comment: Maybe. It's difficult to say without being able to see all your code. Generally speaking, object lifetimes need to be managed very carefully. Any objects that depend on each other should have the same lifetime, and  your DI container should manage all those object. For example, if your `UserManager` has a different lifetime than the `UserStore` you inject into it, that could cause a problem, or if only `UserStore` were managed by your DI container, but not `UserManager`. Also, in the context of a web application, everything should be "request" scoped. Anything else is likely to cause issues.

Comment: By any chance context being used in `using` block anywhere? I hope the lifetime of DbContext is request scope

Comment: @Developer not in any part of the code that is being executed as part of this call

Comment: How is `LocalContext` managed inside `UnitOfWork`? Could you post that code?

Comment: @Developer LocalContext is being used for other methods and is working fine so I am sure it is not the problem

Comment: The reason for asking reg `LocalContext` is that, if Im not wrong, as per the DI configuration when `DbContext` is requested, its served by the instance of `LocalContext` - `container.RegisterWebApiRequest<DbContext>(() => new LocalContext("name=DefaultConnection"));` . What is the lifetime of `LocalContext` ? If its request scope or singleton and if LocalScope is disposed inside UnitOfWork, then thats gonna affect the `DbContext` as well. Its hard to find out the issue with the code you have provided, issue is happening in some other place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to do with this line:

```
container.Register<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, UserStore <ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Because of lifestlye.scoped, the context was being disposed of at this point.

I needed to add this to the `container`:

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();
```

from these instructions: http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#perwebrequest

Which only disposed of the object at the end of the web request